# Change Enum With OOP PHP

Tags: php, mysql, enums

I'm new to learning web development with PHP and I have a problem I'm trying to solve. I have an ENUM type in my database which is of 2 values: "Y" or "N". It is called userStatus inside my user table (tbl_users). I'm trying to use PHP to change that ENUM value for that particular user when a button is clicked. However when I click the button nothing happens and I'm unsure if its the button or my PHP or a combination of both being wrong which is causing this not to work?

PHP to change ENUM:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-activate'])){

  if(isset($_GET['id']))
  {
   $id = $_GET['id'];
   extract($user_home->getID($userId));

   $statusY = "Y";
   $statusN = "N";

$stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT userID,userStatus FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uID");
$stmt->execute(array(":userID"=>$userId));
$row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
if($row['userStatus']==$statusN)
{
$stmt = $user->runQuery("UPDATE tbl_users SET userStatus=:status WHERE userId=:userID");
$stmt->bindparam(":status",$statusY);
$stmt->bindparam(":userID",$userId);
$stmt->execute();

$msg = "
          <div class='alert alert-success'>
    <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
    <strong>WoW !</strong>  Your Account is Now Activated : <a href='manage_users.php'></a>
       </div>
       ";
}
else
{
$msg = "
          <div class='alert alert-error'>
    <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
    <strong>sorry !</strong>  Your Account is allready Activated : <a href='manage_users.php'></a>
       </div>
       ";
}
}
else
{
$msg = "
      <div class='alert alert-error'>
   <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
   <strong>sorry !</strong>  No Account Found : <a href='manage_users.php'></a>
   </div>
   ";
}
}
}
```

Get user id function:

```
 public function getID($userId)
 {
  $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userId=:id");
  $stmt->execute(array(":id"=>$userId));
  $editRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  return $editRow;
 }
```

Table Which displays users:

```
  $database = new Database();
  $db = $database->dbConnection();
  $conn = $db;


          $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users";
          $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
          $stmt->execute();
          while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
          ?>
          <tr>

            <td><?php echo $row['userID']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['userName']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['userFirstName']."&nbsp;".$row['userSurname']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['userEmail']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['userRole']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['userStatus']?></td>

          <td>
```

And My button at the end of the table which should, when clicked, run the PHP at the to:

```
                <?php if($row['userStatus'] == ('N')){
               echo '  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" name="btn-activate" ></i> Activate</button>';
                }else{
                  echo '  <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"></i> Archive</button>';
                } ?>
                <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal" data-id="<?php echo $row['userID']; ?>" id="getUser" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</button>

              </td>
            </tr>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no code (nothing happens) if either of the first two `if` conditions don't evaluate to TRUE.

Consider adding some debugging output. At least add an `else` for each of those ifs and `echo` some debug output.

---

Very strange that the code is checking both `$_POST` and `$_GET`. I suspect that `id` is being passed in on the form submit, just like `btn-activate`, and not as a parameter in the uri.  (i.e. Did you mean `$_POST['id']` ? Just guessing here.

We see a reference to `$userid` in this line:

```
extract($user_home->getID($userId));
```

But we don't see what value is assigned to `$userId`. The preceding line attempts to set a variable named `$id`. But we don't see `$id` being used anywhere else.

Personally, I'd avoid using the `extract` function where it isn't specifically needed. (I don't want my code susceptible to malfunctioning, in this example,  when someone adds a column to tbl_users.)

http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

Put the `name` attribute to your button, not in the `<i>` element.

```
<?php

    if($row['userStatus'] == ('N')){

        echo '  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="btn-activate"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Activate</button>';

    } else {

        echo '  <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"></i> Archive</button>';

    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but still having the same problem. Nothing is happening?